# Verilog code for solving a logic gate has this error: Invalid module instantiation

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

[image: Schematic]

I was going through a book, and there is this exercise that I need to solve with Verilog. I wrote this code, but it's giving me this error:

```
main.v:20: syntax error
main.v:20: error: Invalid module instantiation
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Code is:

```
module Exercise(A,B,C);
  input A,B;
  output C;
  wire w1,w2;
    
  not not1(w1,B);
  or or1(w2,B,w1);
  or or2(C,A,w2);
endmodule

module main;
  reg A,B;
  wire C;
  
  Exercise exer1(C,A,B);
  
  initial 
      begin
      A = 0;
      B = 1;
      #5;
      $display("Result = ",C);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the connections to the module instance.  You connected a `reg` to the module output: `B` in the `main` module is connected to `C` in the `Exercise` module.

You are using connection by order, but you should use connection by name.

Change:

```
  Exercise exer1(C,A,B);
```

to:

```
  Exercise exer1 (.C(C), .A(A), .B(B));
```

Here is the new `main` module.

```
module main;
  reg A,B;
  wire C;
  
    Exercise exer1 (.C(C), .A(A), .B(B));

  initial 
      begin
      A = 0;
      B = 1;
      #5;
      $display("Result = ",C);
    end
endmodule
```

Your simulator error message is not very specific.  You can get more helpful error messages with other simulators which are available on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/vEe_).  This link has a complete, runnable code example which proves that the code no longer has a syntax error.

See also: [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)